# Using request data outside of routing endpoint

Tags: python, api, flask, routes, httprequest

I am using Flask for an API. In one of my routing endpoints, I want to use a model instance with the flask.request object's remote_user attribute for a default value.

The class definition of my model is:

```
class Results(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'results'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    sid = Column(Integer)
    attribute = Column(String(2048))
    value_s = Column(String(2048))
    value_d = Column(Float)
    user = Column(String(48), default=request.remote_user)
```

The problem is I need to define this class outside of the endpoint, but when I use the request object outside of an endpoint I get the error: `RuntimeError: working outside of request context.`

As a test, I tried defining the class in the endpoint, and it works for the first time I hit the endpoint and instantiated the model, but when I hit the endpoint after that I get an error that `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table '[tablename]' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.`

I will need to use this model class in another endpoint, so how can I define my model class with the request object outside of the request context in my endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flask.request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/reqcontext/) is a proxy that is valid only during a request. The models are added to `MetaData` [on startup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/hcfDfpxZ50g), so it tries to resolve the default value `request.remote_address` before a request is received.

When you move the model declaration to the api layer, the models are instantiated on every request, which throws an error since `MetaData` accepts only unique table names.

SQLAlchemy allows you to define a function as the default value of the field. The difference here is that the callable is executed only on insert or update. So if you define your field as:

```
user = Column(String(48), default=lambda: request.remote_user)
```

`request` gets resolved only when you interact with the db. The caveat with this is that you won't be able to use this model class when you're not in a request context.

Comment: That is perfect and fits my use cases just right. Thanks! I was banging my head over this. Now I see the utility of using a lambda function.